# How to position and delay the tooltipDialog in Extension Library

Tags: dialog, tooltip, dojo, xpages

I am using the tooltipDialog from extlib and want to position the tooltip to the left and right instead of the default which seem to be below.

any idea how to do this?

== Update ==

Found the following code in extlib
eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls\resources\web\extlib\dijit\TooltipDialog.js

so I tried a few different options, but could not get it to work
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dijit-TooltipDialog-orientation-of-popup-td1007523.html

XSP.openTooltipDialog("#{id:tooltipDialog1}","#{id:link2}","orient:{BR:'BL',BL:'BR'}")
XSP.openTooltipDialog("#{id:tooltipDialog1}","#{id:link2}","orient:[BR:'BL',BL:'BR']")

```
XSP.openTooltipDialog = function xe_otd(dialogId,_for,options,params) {
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    var created = false
    var dlg = dijit.byId(dialogId)
    if(!dlg) {
        options = dojo.mixin({dojoType:"extlib.dijit.TooltipDialog"},options)
        dojo.parser.instantiate([dojo.byId(dialogId)],options);
        dlg = dijit.byId(dialogId)
        created = true;
    } else {
        if(dlg.keepComponents) {
            dijit.popup.open({
                popup: dlg, 
                around: dojo.byId(_for)
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    if(created) {
        dojo.connect(dlg, 'onBlur', function(){
            dijit.popup.close(dlg);
        })
    }
    dlg.attr("content", "<div id='"+dialogId+":_content'></div>");
    var onComplete = function() {
        dijit.popup.open({
            popup: dlg, 
            around: dojo.byId(_for)
        });
        dlg.focus();
    }
    var axOptions = {
        "params": dojo.mixin({'$$showdialog':true,'$$created':created},params),
        "onComplete": onComplete,
        "formId": dialogId
    }
    XSP.partialRefreshGet(dialogId+":_content",axOptions)
})
```

}

btw: I also need to set the showDelay

also found these usefull links
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/TooltipDialog

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the following dojo attribute:

```
<xp:dojoAttribute name="data-dojo-props" value="position:['before']">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
```

Comment: data-dojo-props may be for the wrong version of Dojo. If the Dojo property is orient, try using that in the dojoAttribute instead, with the relevant setting.

Answer (score 1):

Atleast in dojo-1.8.1,

```
dijit.popup.open({
    popup: dlg, 
    around: node,
    orient: ["after-centered"]
});
```

places the ToolTipDialog to right of node.

Answer (score 0):

The "position" attribute of the tooltip control supports values of "above", "below", "left", and "right".

Comment: thanks tim, I did try this but could not get it to work


<xe:tooltipDialog id="tooltipDialog1" partialRefresh="true" style="width:300px;height:150px" dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
<xe:this.dojoAttributes>
 <xp:dojoAttribute name="position" value="left"></xp:dojoAttribute>
</xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:tooltipDialog>

Comment: I think you have looked at the Tooltip control. can't find anything about positioning for the TooltipDialog